# SQL Query to split row values into separate columns with only one record

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Our Oracle 11g database has a table that tracks changes to a document, similar to the following:

```
ID  |     DATE     | STATUS_ID
203 |  10-02-2017  |   2
203 |  10-04-2017  |   3
168 |  08-15-2017  |   2
203 |  11-01-2017  |   4
```

I'd like to some how make 2 new columns with records based on the date/status_id of the above table.  The data above would be converted to the following (Status 2 = Open, Status 4 = Closed; I don't need any other statuses):

```
ID  |   OPEN_DATE  |   CLOSED_DATE
203 |  10-02-2017  |  11-01-2017
168 |  08-15-2017  |    NULL
```

I think that this is similar to a pivot table or crosstab query from Excel or Access but I'm not sure how to approach this.  I'd like to ensure that each document ID only has 1 row and the applicable status dates are put in the right columns.

Any and all guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple option that avoids the cost of joins, conditional aggregation...

```
SELECT
  ID, 
  MIN(CASE WHEN status = 2 THEN date END)  AS DATE_OPEN, 
  MAX(CASE WHEN status = 4 THEN date END)  AS DATE_CLOSED
FROM
  yourTable
WHERE
  status IN (2, 4)
GROUP BY
  ID
```

Comment: This is perfect.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
select t1.id, t1.date AS 'fromdate', t2.date AS 'todate'
from 
    (SELECT id,date FROM `newtracker` WHERE status= 2) t1
left join
    (SELECT id,date FROM `newtracker` WHERE status = 4) t2
on
    t1.id = t2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
select a.*,b.end_date
from
(select id,date as start_date
from test
where  status_id = 2 ) a
left join
(select id,date as end_date
from test
where  status_id = 4 ) b
on a.id = b.id;
```

Let me know in case of any queries/explanation required.